# Swift - Make async calls in collection view - Resetting data via prepareForReuse() method doesn't work

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have this method to put data into my dataSource array which is used for my collection view

```
private func fetchInitialData() {
    
    for index in self.HITSSOURCE_CHALLENGE_COPY_COUNT..<self.challengeHitsInteractor.numberOfHits() {
        
        if let jsonChallengeObject: Hit<JSON> = try? self.challengeHitsInteractor.hit(atIndex: index),
            
            let challengeObject: Challenge = try? Challenge(json: jsonChallengeObject.object) {
            let challengeProfileItem = ChallengeProfileItem()
            challengeProfileItem.challengeObject = challengeObject
            self.HITSSOURCE_CHALLENGE_COPY_COUNT = self.challengeHitsInteractor.numberOfHits()
            self.dataSource.append(challengeProfileItem)
            
        }
        
    }

    for index in self.HITSSOURCE_TOURNAMENT_COPY_COUNT..<self.tournamentHitsInteractor.numberOfHits() {
       
        if let jsonTournamentObject: Hit<JSON> = try? self.tournamentHitsInteractor.hit(atIndex: index),
            
            let tournamentObject: Tournament = try? Tournament(json: jsonTournamentObject.object) {
            let tournamentProfileItem = TournamentProfileItem()
            tournamentProfileItem.tournamentObject = tournamentObject
            self.HITSSOURCE_TOURNAMENT_COPY_COUNT = self.tournamentHitsInteractor.numberOfHits()
            self.dataSource.append(tournamentProfileItem)
            
        }
    }
    
    self.eventCollectionView?.reloadData()
}^
```

Now, in the cellForItemAt delegate method, I am **iterating** through this dataSource
array

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    self.hideActivityView()
    
    let myChallengesCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyEventsCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyEventsCollectionViewCell
    
    myChallengesCell.delegate = self

    if (self.challengeHitsInteractor.numberOfHits() + self.tournamentHitsInteractor.numberOfHits() == 0) {
        
        return myChallengesCell
        
    }
    
    if self.displayedIndices.contains(indexPath.row) {
       
        return myChallengesCell
        
    }
    
    else {
        
        let abstractProfileItem = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        self.displayedIndices.insert(indexPath.row)
        
        myChallengesCell.indexPath = indexPath
        
        switch abstractProfileItem.challengeType {
           
            case .singleChallenge:
                
                var challengeProfileItem = abstractProfileItem as! ChallengeProfileItem
                challengeProfileItem = myChallengesCell.setupCellWithChallengeProfileItem(challengeObject: challengeProfileItem.challengeObject) as! ChallengeProfileItem
                myChallengesCell.setEventTitle(abstractEvent: challengeProfileItem.challengeObject)
                self.dataSource[indexPath.row] = challengeProfileItem
```

..

in my **MyEventsCollectionViewCell** cell, I setup some properties synchronously, however, some other data need to be fetched from the database on the fly

```
 public func setupCellWithChallengeProfileItem(challengeObject:Challenge) -> AbstractProfileItem {
    
    self.challengeProfileItem = ChallengeProfileItem()
    self.challengeProfileItem?.delegate = self
    
    self.setEventTitle(abstractEvent: challengeObject)
    self.checkIfToAddOrRemovePlayIcon(abstractEvent: challengeObject)
    
    self.challengeProfileItem.challengeObject = challengeObject

    challengeObject.eventType = .singleChallenge
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        self.challengeProfileItem.populateChallengeObject(challengeObject: challengeObject)
        
    }

    return self.challengeProfileItem
    
}
```

The **ChallengeProfileItem** looks like this

```
public func populateChallengeObject(challengeObject:Challenge)  {
    
    self.userDataAccessService.checkIfUserIsBlocked(completionHandler: { (userExists, isSourceUserBlocked, isTargetUserBlocked, userId) in
        
        if (!userExists || isSourceUserBlocked || isTargetUserBlocked) {
            
            return
            
        }
        
        else {
            
            self.challengeParticipationDataAccessService.fetchParticipationByUserIdChallengeId(completionHandler: { (participationObject) in
                   
                self.ratingDataAccessService.fetchRatingByEventIdAndParticipantId(completionHandler: { (numberOfRating) in
                       
                    self.numberOfRating = numberOfRating
                                        
                    self.delegate?.didFetchRating(eventType: .singleChallenge, eventId: challengeObject.id, rating: numberOfRating)
                                          
                }, participantId: participationObject.userId, eventId: participationObject.challengeId)
                                           
            }, userId: challengeObject.organizerId!, challengeId: challengeObject.id!)
                
                
            self.challengeResourceService.identifyRankingOfParticipant(completionHandler: { (ranking, numberOfParticipants) in
                   
                self.ranking = ranking
                self.numberOfParticipants = numberOfParticipants
                                  
                self.delegate?.didFetchRankingAndNumberOfParticipants(eventType: .singleChallenge, eventId: challengeObject.id, ranking: ranking, numberOfParticipants: numberOfParticipants)
                
            }, challengeId: challengeObject.id!)
            
            
            self.challengeDataAccessService.fetchDownloadURLOfChallengeImage(challengeId: challengeObject.id!) { (contentURL) in
                
                self.delegate?.didFetchContentURL(eventType: .singleChallenge, eventId: challengeObject.id, contentURL: contentURL!)
            }
            
        }

   }, sourcePersonId: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, targetPersonId: challengeObject.organizerId!)
}
```

Once the data is fetched, I go back to the view with my collection view by using **delegates**. On the view where my collection view is located, I'll try to update the specific cell by using an index.

```
extension MyEventsView:MyEventsCollectionViewCellDelegate {

 func didFetchContentURL(eventType: EventType, eventId: String, contentURL: URL) {
  
    if let index = self.findIndexForEventItem(withID: eventId) {
       
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

       
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          
            if let cell = self.eventCollectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyEventsCollectionViewCell {
                
                self.dataSource[indexPath.row].contentURL = contentURL
                
                let challengeProfileItem = self.dataSource[indexPath.row] as! ChallengeProfileItem
                print(challengeProfileItem.challengeObject.title)
                print(cell.challengeTitleLabel?.text)
                
                cell.challengeImageView!.sd_setImage(with: contentURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like, there is a mismatch of data. The displayed image doesn't match the challenge title attribute. I know cells are designed to be re-used but when I tried to reset the data within the **prepareForReuse(**) method, the challenge title was displayed at all.

I am struggling with this issue unfortunately..